# create record for nested json element

Tags: json, extjs

I have following json data now i want to create a record based on this rite now i have following structure to create record but i don;t know how would i put the CONTACT_INFO as a nested element

Note: i am directly reading values from GRID ( but from a grid i am not getting nested element CONTACT_INFO and then want to create record )

***RECORD***

```
var record=  Ext.data.Record.create([

                { name: 'CANDI_SR_NO'}, 
                { name: 'CANDI_NAME'}, 
                { name: 'CANDI_CASTE_BAR'},  
                { name: 'CANDI_IS_NRI'},  
                { name: 'CANDI_CASTE'},  
                { name: 'CANDI_SUB_CASTE'},  
                { name: 'CANDI_STATUS'},  
                { name: 'CANDI_AGE'},  
                { name: 'CANDI_HEIGHT'},  
                { name: 'CANDI_NATIVE_PLACE'},  
                { name: 'CANDI_EDUCATION'},  
                { name: 'CANDI_DESIGNATION'},  
                { name: 'CANDI_COMPANY'},  
                { name: 'CANDI_EMAIL_1'},               
                { name: 'CANDI_EMAIL_2'},
                { name: 'CANDI_EMAIL_3'},
                { name: 'CON_L_1'},  
                { name: 'CON_L_2'},  
                { name: 'CON_L_3'},  
                { name: 'CON_M_1'},  
                { name: 'CON_M_2'},  
                { name: 'CON_M_3'},  
                { name: 'CANDI_SALARY'},                        
                { name: 'CANDI_COMMENT'},

                    ]);
```

***JSON***

```
[
  {
    "CANDI_SR_NO": "12",
    "CANDI_NAME": "XYZ",
    "CANDI_CASTE_BAR": false,
    "CANDI_IS_NRI": "false",
    "CANDI_CASTE": "RAS",
    "CANDI_SUB_CASTE": "",
    "CANDI_STATUS": "",
    "CANDI_AGE": "",
    "CANDI_NATIVE_PLACE": "",
    "CANDI_EDUCATION": "",
    "CANDI_DESIGNATION": "",
    "CANDI_COMPANY": "",
    "CONTACT_INFO": 
      {
        "CANDI_EMAIL_1": "asdf",
        "CANDI_EMAIL_2": "",
        "CANDI_EMAIL_3": "",
        "CON_L_1": "asdf",
        "CON_L_2": "",
        "CON_L_3": "",
        "CON_M_1": "",
        "CON_M_2": "",
        "CON_M_3": ""
      }
    ,
    "CANDI_SALARY": "",       
    "CANDI_COMMENT": ""
  }
]
```

I want to send a data in a json format as above but once i click on submit button of a form. so i am asking how to create a Record in extjs so that i can send nested element inside json

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for [`mapping`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/docs/source/DataField.html#cfg-Ext.data.Field-mapping).

As in:

```
{ name: 'CANDI_EMAIL_1', mapping: 'CONTACT_INFO.CANDI_EMAIL_1'},
```

For writing, you will also need to update the `toHash` function of the `Ext.data.JsonWriter` you're using. The default one cannot handle nested objects.

The easiest way may be to write a specific `toHash` function and not a generalised one. Given a `Ext.data.Record` like this:

```
var rec = new record({
  ...
  'CANDI_EMAIL_1': 'foo@example.com'
  ...
});
```

You'd then use a JsonWriter like this:

```
CandiWriter = Ext.extend(Ext.data.JsonWriter, {
  toHash: function(rec) {
    return {
      CONTACT_INFO: {
        CANDI_EMAIL_1: rec.get('CANDI_EMAIL_1')
      }
    };
  }
})
```

You can write a generalised one if you expect to do this a lot, but I expect that it would take longer than just maintaining a specialised `JsonWriter`.

Comment: Well i guess this mapping is for receiving data from JSON , i want to send JSON with a nested field

Comment: Well do you have any example like where i can find how to override hash function of jsonWriter

Comment: In my answer I gave a way to override it by making a subclass of `JsonWriter`. You'd then use an instance of `CandiWriter` for your writer instead of one of `JsonWriter`.

Comment: so that means i need to pass CandiWriter in my JsonStore ?

Comment: var candiWriter = new CandiWriter(); and passed it as 
var storeGroom = new Ext.data.Store({
    id: 'storegroom',
    restful: true,   
    proxy: proxyGroom,
    autoSave:false,
    reader: reader,
    writer: candiWriter    
});

after writing this code m not getting the nested element it is still behaving like the default one

Comment: Ah. My bad. Looks like it might be the `render` function instead. http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/docs/source/JsonWriter.html#method-Ext.data.JsonWriter-render